# How can I write Method that will find price of the item and return it Item index in the ITEMS array is corresponding to the index in the PRICES array

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class OnlineCTStores {
    //avaliable store items
    public static String[] ITEMS = {"Cactus", "T Shirt", "air", "Terracotta Necklace", "Coffee Mug", "Wood Crate Wall Storage", "Blanket", "Knife", "Copper Coffee and Tea Kettle", "Wall Art", 
            "Marble Clock", "Natural Bench", "Llama Valley Framed Print", "Gold Metal Frame Mirror", "Fork", "Star Wars game", "Barracuda", "Anchor", "Sunlight", "planet Saturn"}; 
    //corresponding prices
    public static double[] PRICES = {49.99, 13.99, 5.99, 14.99, 29.99, 11.50, 79.99, 23.80, 27.99, 39.44, 78.40, 299.30, 55.00, 176.89, 4.99, 67.00, 8.19, 50.00, 1500, 400};

    public double findItemPrice(String item){
        //TODO

        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you haven't tried it yourself? If not, why not?

Comment: Use a `Map<String, Double>`

Comment: if you're going to return an index then wouldn't it be better to return an integer? rather than a double.

Comment: @Aominè I think he wants to return a price in that method.

Comment: `int place = Arrays.asList(ITEMS).indexOf(item);` `return PRICES[place];`

Answer (score 2):

For better time complexity you could sort ITEMS array and call binary search function. Sorting is O(nlogn) and search is O(logn).

```
public double findItemPrice(String item){
   Arrays.sort(ITEMS);
   int matchIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(ITEMS, item);
   if (matchIndex == -1) throw new RuntimeException("Item price  not found, " + 
   input);
   return PRICES[matchIndex];
}
```

**Update**

Arrays.sort() will modify existing array. If you want to keep it untouched, you may want to copy it to new array:

```
int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(ITEMS, ITEMS.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a map to do this. For example, if you were to use a `Map<String, Double>`, just use the `Map.get(input)` to get the price double. You just have to initialise the `Map` with repeated `Map.put(String, Double)` calls. This could be done with static initialisation, like:

```
Map<String, Double> itemPrices = new HashMap<>();
static {
    itemPrices.put("Cactus", 49.99);
    ...
}
```

And then, instead of having a method to do this, you could just say: `double price = itemPrices.get("Cactus")`.

However, if you really have to keep using arrays with synchronised indices, then you could write your method like this:

```
public static double findItemPrice(String input) {
    int matchIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < ITEMS.length; i++)
        if (input.equals(ITEMS[i])) {
            matchIndex = i;
            break;
        }

    if (matchIndex == -1) throw new RuntimeException("String not found, " + input);
    return PRICES[matchIndex];
}
```